# Superfish Supersubs <li> menu items width

Tags: menu, width, superfish

I've been stuck on this one for some time now and would really appreciate some assistance.
I'm developing a superfish horizontal dropdown menu.

I would like to know how to, using supersubs, set the width of the dropdown menu items to that of the largest items width in the drop down.

The default is : `$('ul.sf-menu').supersubs({ minWidth: 40, maxWidth: 41,  extraWidth:  1 }).superfish();`

I would like something like : `$('ul.sf-menu').supersubs({ minWidth: 40, **maxWidth: auto or 100%**,  extraWidth:  1 }).superfish();`

I would appreciate any help at all.

Regards,
Byron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supersubs min and maxwidth are in em's not % or pixels

Comment: Thanks, i got this sorted. 

For anyone wondering, my problem was that i was calling the supersubs on sf-menu before the DOM had loaded, which obviously didnt resize the elements to the largest width.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with supersubs being a little buggy, and I figured out a superior CSS-only alternative. The drop-down `<UL>` and it's `<LI>` children should have no width set (or `width:auto;` if needed, I suppose), and both should be set to `display:block;`

```
#nav li ul a { display:block; width:auto; white-space:no-wrap; }
```

You can see an example at http://epraxadev.com/clcnewport/comp/supersubs.html

Comment: Whoops. This doesn't work if the menu items need to be the same width (like in a menu where the background-color of a link changes on hover)